# jQuery fadeIn is instant with large element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I a using a function to fade in an element with jQuery. This is the bit of code:

```
$("#inventory").fadeIn("fast");
```

It works no problem, every time it's called it works exactly as intended. However, one particular instance of this event, when the #inventory element is very large, the fadeIn is instant. The other thing is, I have a loading image that fades out before the inventory fades in. With this large element, the loading image (gif) stops animating for a second, then instantly disappears, followed by the instant appearance of the #inventory element.

Is there a technical limitation to fadeIn that is causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probable reason for this is your **PC limitation**. Graphic card can't manage to animate the fade effect of such big image.

Comment: That seems the most logical, as soon as I make the element smaller (it's a table so I removed a lot of the rows) it animates just fine. I was kind of suspecting this to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try your same scenario with 100x100 px image, see if you have the same results, or it just your code delegations.